# Function not defined and error when calling functions from app.js in html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax

I'm trying to have two functions called on mouseover and onclick in html. Here is my home.html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../app.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ProfileImage" onmouseover="test2()" onclick="ajaxmagic()"> </div>
```

Here is my app.js file:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;

var server = app.listen(8085, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:8085');
});
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

function test2() {
    console.log("TeSTING");
}

function ajaxmagic() {
$.ajax({
    url : 'FetchSongs.php',
    type : 'POST',
    data : {username: "maxolgin"},
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function (result) {

    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

    var table = document.getElementById("myMixTable");
    table.style.borderCollapse = "seperate"

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    console.log(table.rows.length)
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var row2 = table.insertRow(1);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.rowSpan = "2"
    cell1.style.width = "75px"
    cell1.setAttribute("class", "MixImage")

    var image = document.createElement("img");
    initialString = result[i].songImage
    outString1 = initialString.replace("{w}", "500")
    outStringFinal = outString1.replace("{h}", "500")
    image.src = outStringFinal
    image.style.width = "75px"
    cell1.appendChild(image)

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell2.style.width = "300px"

    var title = document.createElement("td");
    title.innerHTML = result[i].songTitle
    title.style.fontSize = "16"
    cell2.appendChild(title);

    var artistCell = row2.insertCell(0);

    var artistTitle = document.createElement("td");

    artistTitle.innerHTML = "Drizzy"
    artistTitle.style.fontSize = "13px"
    artistCell.appendChild(artistTitle);

    var timestampCell = row.insertCell(2);
    timestampCell.rowSpan = "2"
    timestampCell.style.horizAlign = "right"

    var timestamp = document.createElement("td");
    timestamp.style.horizAlign = "right"
    timestampCell.appendChild(timestamp);

    }

    },
    error : function () {
        alert("error123");
    }
    });
```

As you can see, ajaxMagic and test2 are both clearly defined. On mouseover, when calling test2() I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: test2 is not defined`. And onClick an alert pops up that says `MySite.com says "Error"`

Why can I not call these functions?

Comment: What's wrong with it?  Should I include the full path

Comment: Changed it to ```/var/www/html/app.js``` (its actual path) and it still didn't work

Comment: Can you show the directory structure and where `home and app` files are located?

Comment: Both app.js and home.html are located in /var/www/inc

Comment: Change to `src="./app.js"` and try again. Two dots means go one directory back but when the files are in same dir then you can use `src="filename"` to import `js` file.